# To generate a question for a given user in PostgreSQL by PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a list of URLs in my homepage which is like SO in the following form

```
<a href="?questions&questions=777">link1</a>
<a href="?questions&questions=666">link2</a>
```

The following PHP script has a problem in the parameter of `$_GET`.

```
 $dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=masi user=masi password=123");
 // A QUESTION SELECTED BY USER 
 // to generate the answers for the given question 
     $result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "query9", "SELECT title, answer
         FROM answers 
         WHERE questions_question_id = $1;");            // WARNINGS refer HERE
     // TODO I am not sure if the syntax is correct for parametr inside $_GET                             
     $result = pg_execute($dbconn, "query9", array($_GET["'question_id' = $questions_question_id"]));
           // Problem HERE inside the $_GET
```

*Thank you to Nos and Jikhan for solving the problem with $dbconn and
to Simon for solving the main problem of this thread!*

**How can you get only the question_id from the URL such that Postgres understand the query?**

Comment: the error says that $dbconn isn't valid. Where do you connect to the database ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the problem is not the query but the connection to the database (dbconn)

Answer (score 1):

Your $_GET statement also looks rather strange. I don't know what the point of repeating 'questions' in your link is but if we assume your links are formatted as so:

```
<a href="?questions=777">link1</a>
```

You can get access to the ID 777 as so:

```
$question_id = $_GET['questions'];
```

I believe pg_execute() just expects the array of values in the order you write them in the prepare statement. So you don't need to try to assign the variable $questions_question_id - this simply won't work.

I'd also ensure this contains what you expect it to (i.e. just an ID number).

```
$question_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'questions', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

The filter family of functions are available in PHP 5.2 and get rid of any unwanted characters. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

filter_input() returns null if the GET variable isn't set.

Comment: **Do you need the explicit sanitizing, since we use `pg_prepare`?** I feel that `pg_prepare` sanitizes the input automatically.

Comment: sanitizing will only remove dangerous characters such as semi-colons. It won't guarantee the ID variable is actually a number. For security you still need to ensure the ID is just an integer. It's always worth filtering incoming variables and preparing all SQL!

Comment: Why is it important for security to make sure its an integer? if it isn't, surly it would just return no results?

Comment: it's good practise to filter incoming data just to make sure it is what you expect it to be. You are right though, in this example if you're just matching IDs it should return nothing. It's more important in examples such as posting comments where you'd want to strip tags to avoid things like JavaScript. I wrote the above over a year ago, so I presume that was my line of thinking at the time!