# To sanitize all user's input in PostgreSQL by PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, sanitize

This question is based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249671/to-generate-a-question-for-a-given-user-in-postgresql-by-php/1249816#1249816).

**Do you need the explicit sanitizing when you use pg_prepare?**

I feel that pg_prepare sanitizes the user's input automatically such that we do not need this

```
 $question_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'questions', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

**Context where I use Postgres**

```
 $result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "query9", "SELECT title, answer
     FROM answers 
     WHERE questions_question_id = $1;");                                  
 $result = pg_execute($dbconn, "query9", array($_GET['question_id']));
```

Comment: How does the filter_input() function have anything to do with postgres...or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Postgres [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php) on `pg_prepare`, all escaping is done for you. See the examples section where it lists the following code (including the comments):

```
<?php
// Connect to a database named "mary"
$dbconn = pg_connect("dbname=mary");

// Prepare a query for execution
$result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "my_query", 'SELECT * FROM shops WHERE name = $1');

// Execute the prepared query.  Note that it is not necessary to escape
// the string "Joe's Widgets" in any way
$result = pg_execute($dbconn, "my_query", array("Joe's Widgets"));

// Execute the same prepared query, this time with a different parameter
$result = pg_execute($dbconn, "my_query", array("Clothes Clothes Clothes"));
?>
```

Though it may be useful to note that they use single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`) around the query string, as then `$1` won't accidentally get interpolated into the string.